# How to specify both Center and Graphics directives for Dividers option in Grid?

Tags: options, grid-layouts, style

The docs for `Dividers` give an example featuring `Center` as the setting for the the `Dividers` option in a `Grid` expression:

```
Grid[Table[x, {3}, {7}], Dividers -> Center]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

...and also some examples where `Graphics` directives are given as the setting for this option; e.g.

```
Grid[Table[x, {4}, {7}],
     Dividers -> {{2 -> Red, -2 -> Blue}, {2 -> Red, -2 -> Blue}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

...but they say nothing about how to specify both `Center` *and* a `Graphics` directive for this option.

---

**Q:** Is there a way to specify both `Center` *and* `Graphics` directives for `Grid`'s `Dividers` option?

---

FWIW, here are some of my failed attempts at guessing the answer to this question:

```
Grid[Table[x, {3}, {7}], Dividers -> {Center -> Red}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[Table[x, {3}, {7}], Dividers -> {Center -> Red, Center -> Blue}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[Table[x, {3}, {7}], Dividers -> {{Center -> Red}, {Center -> Blue}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[Table[x, {3}, {7}], Dividers -> {Center, Red}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

(It should go without saying that the last result above is no good; the goal here is to apply both types of specifications to the same dividers simultaneously.)

```
Grid[Table[x, {3}, {7}], Dividers -> Directive[Center, Red]]
```

Fails with

> An improperly formatted directive with head Symbol was encountered.

Comment: Would specifying color for all and removing first and last divider be of any interest?

Comment: @Stitch: sure (I see that one of gwr's solutions take that approach)

Comment: Right, I was thinking about exactly this. This is not ideal relative to your question, but you can be pretty flexible there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Single Color for Center Dividers

```
Grid[ Table[x, {3}, {7}], Dividers -> Center, FrameStyle -> Red ]
```

> [image: SingleColor]

### Different Colors for Center Dividers

```
With[
   {
       horizontalColor = Blue,
       verticalColor   = Red
   },
   Grid[ 
       Table[x, {3}, {7}], 
       Dividers -> {{None, {verticalColor}, None}, {None, {horizontalColor}, None}}
   ]
]
```

> [image: TwoColors]

By adding another color right after `verticalColor` or `horizontalColor` you can make the colors for the center alternating. The specs for drawing frames can pretty much match anything, you want.

Answer (score 4):

The expanded form of `Center` is `{False, {True}, False}` as seen by looking at Box form:

```
Grid[Table[x, {3}, {7}], Dividers -> Center] // ToBoxes // First // Options
```

> ```
> {AutoDelete -> False, 
>  GridBoxDividers -> {"Columns" -> {False, {True}, False}, 
>    "Rows" -> {False, {True}, False}}, 
>  GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}}
> ```

We can replace `True` with style directives as desired.  So we may write:

```
styleCenter[r_] := styleCenter[r, r];
styleCenter[r_, c_] := {False, {#}, False} & /@ {r, c}

Grid[Table[x, {3}, {7}], Dividers -> styleCenter[Red]]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Table[x, {3}, {7}], Dividers -> styleCenter[{Thick, Blue}, Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: @gwr Thanks.  I voted for your answer as well, of course.